# Windows File Explorer folder icon displaying incorrect

Tags: directory, icons, microsoft-file-explorer

I have this particular folder (C:\Code) where most of the folder icons underneath it displays incorrectly.  Anywhere else is fine. Tried clearing the icon cache but that didn't fix it.  Even if I change the name of the folders, the wrong icon seems to stick.  Tried changing the icon of the folder in File properties/Customize but that still didn't fix it.  Also the File Open dialog shows the folder icons correctly.

[image]

Change folder icon..

[image]